# CMake can't build VTK project on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, vtk, vcpkg

I am trying to make a C++ program using VTK that is built with CMake on ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I installed VTK with vcpkg. However, when I try to build the project, I get this:

```
CMake Error at /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/vtk/FindLZMA.cmake:5 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create ALIAS target "LZMA::LZMA" because target
  "LibLZMA::LibLZMA" is imported but not globally visible.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/vtk/VTK-vtk-module-find-packages.cmake:1196 (find_package)
  /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/vtk/vtk-config.cmake:136 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Found LZMA: /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/liblzma.a (found version "5.2.5") 
-- Found utf8cpp: /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/utf8cpp  
-- Found JPEG: /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libjpeg.a (found version "62") 
-- Found TIFF: /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libtiff.a (found version "4.3.0") 
-- Found Freetype: /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/lib/libfreetype.a (found version "2.11.1") 
CMake Deprecation Warning at /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/vtk/vtk-use-file-deprecated.cmake:1 (message):
  The `VTK_USE_FILE` is no longer used starting with 8.90.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (include)
```

There seem to be two problems, something about a target "LibLZMA" not being imported globally and a deprecation warning. I don't know how to fix any of these, I searched online for solutions but found no one who had the same problem as this.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(VTKTEST, LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "")
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-linux" CHACHE STRING)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
/home/ilmu011/Desktop/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/vtk
)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)

include("${VTK_USE_FILE}")

add_executable(VTKTEST
main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(VTKTEST PRIVATE ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I reported this problem last week and tested the fix. Here: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23444/commits/593d52744d3a004e40b719fe7bc709c481c7719b](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23444/commits/593d52744d3a004e40b719fe7bc709c481c7719b)

Comment: More discussion here: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/22856#issuecomment-1061764691](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/22856#issuecomment-1061764691)

Comment: I am hoping this gets merged in the next few days. I am not sure if we want to post an answer or not on this one for a temporary bug.

Comment: You should set `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` *before* `project()`

Comment: It was merged yesterday: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23444#event-6245959649](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23444#event-6245959649)